# Setting Google Talk status (with authentication) from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp, google-talk

I'm trying to build a site that updates users' Google Talk statuses from Google App Engine using the built in [XMPP Python API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/overview) (or a third-party one, if one works better than another). I've been looking around for some examples or docs explaining how I would go about doing this, but nothing I find seems to offer a fully functional solution.

App Engine's XMPP Python developer docs suggest that updating a status can be done through the `send_presence()` method ([see here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/overview#Sending_Application_Status)):

```
xmpp.send_presence(to_jid, status="My app's status")
```

But, how would this be authenticated? Wouldn't I have to send the users password with the request? (Ideally, I'd like to do so using OAuth [as suggested here](https://developers.google.com/talk/jep_extensions/oauth).) Am I misunderstanding something?

Please excuse me if I'm missing something obvious, here. I'm pretty new to both Google App Engine and XMPP. Unlike a lot of examples I've found online, I don't want to create a chat "robot"; I merely want to change an existing user's Google Talk status. Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

You can't change someone else' status using the XMPP API.

You can use the XMPP API to represent yourself, or your users (see the description of XMPP addresses in the GAE XMPP API docs).

You cannot send messages or update the status of a gmail user.